# How to mix thousands of WAV files into a single file using NAudio's MixingSampleProvider?

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, mixing

I'm looking for a way to mix thousands of WAV files into a single file using NAudio's `MixingSampleProvider`. I'm building a drum sampler and I'd like to be able to **create a whole song (based on MIDI information) that could then be exported into a single WAV file**.

The issue I'm running into is that the `MixingSampleProvider` has a **limit of 1024 sources** and throws and exception saying `Too many mixer inputs` if that limit is reached. I'm sure this limit is there for a reason, I'd like to know how to achieve my goal despite it.

I've searched through the NAudio demos and [Mark Heath's blog](https://markheath.net/category/naudio), but I haven't found exactly what I need there.

I was thinking I could **split the song into smaller segments (under 1024 sampler inputs)** and merge the separate parts afterwards. Is that the way to go, or is there a better one? Thanks for any advice.

Here's a part of my code:

```cs
public class DrumSampler
{
    private readonly MixingSampleProvider _mixer;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, SampleSource> _cachedSamples = new();

    public DrumSampler()
    {
        var waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 2);
        _mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(waveFormat);

        LoadSamples();
    }

    private void LoadSamples()
    {
        LoadSample("kick", @"C:\Samples\kick.wav");
        LoadSample("snare", @"C:\Samples\snare.wav");
        LoadSample("crash", @"C:\Samples\crash.wav");
    }

    private void LoadSample(string key, string filePath)
    {
        _cachedSamples.Add(key, SampleSource.CreateFromWaveFile(filePath, _mixer.WaveFormat));
    }

    public void ExportSong()
    {
        AddDrums();

        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("song.wav", _mixer);
    }

    private void AddDrums()
    {
        //simulate adding drum samples based on MIDI information 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var sample = _cachedSamples["kick"];
            var delayed = new DelayedSampleProvider(sample, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(123));
            _mixer.AddMixerInput(delayed);
        }
    }
}
```

The `SampleSource` implementation is taken from NAudio's [DrumMachineDemo](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/fb35ce8367f30b8bc5ea84e7d2529e172cf4c381/NAudioWpfDemo/DrumMachineDemo/SampleSource.cs).

The `DelayedSampleProvider` implementation is inspired by NAudio's [OffsetSampleProvider](https://markheath.net/post/naudio-offsetsampleprovider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this issue by splitting the song into smaller chungs (under 1024 mixer inputs), each chunk having its own `MixingSampleProvider` and then concatenating all the chungs using the [`ConcatenatingSampleProvider`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio.Core/Wave/SampleProviders/ConcatenatingSampleProvider.cs).

It works, however, I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution...

Here's my code:

```cs
public class DrumSampler
{
    private readonly WaveFormat _waveFormat;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, SampleSource> _cachedSamples = new();

    public DrumSampler()
    {
        _waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 2);

        LoadSamples();
    }

    private void LoadSamples()
    {
        LoadSample("kick", @"C:\Samples\kick.wav");
        LoadSample("snare", @"C:\Samples\snare.wav");
        LoadSample("crash", @"C:\Samples\crash.wav");
    }

    private void LoadSample(string key, string filePath)
    {
        _cachedSamples.Add(key, SampleSource.CreateFromWaveFile(filePath, _mixer.WaveFormat));
    }

    public void ExportSong()
    {
        var result = GenerateDrumAudio();
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("song.wav", result);
    }

    private ISampleProvider GenerateDrumAudio()
    {
        //simulate reading drum hits from MIDI
        var drumHits = Enumerable.Range(0, 10_000).ToList();

        //split drum hits into chunks of 1024 (max input limit of the mixing sample provider)
        var drumHitChunks = drumHits.Chunk(1024);

        //store all chunk mixers in a list
        var mixers = new List<MixingSampleProvider>();

        foreach (var drumHitChunk in drumHitChunks)
        {
            //for each chunk: create a mixer, add drum hits to it and add it to the mixers list
            var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(_waveFormat);

            foreach (var drumHit in drumHitChunk)
            {
                var sample = _cachedSamples["kick"];
                var delayed = new DelayedSampleProvider(sample, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(123));
                mixer.AddMixerInput(delayed);
            }

            mixers.Add(mixer);
        }

        //concatenate all chunk mixers into a single ISampleProvider
        var mixersConcatenated = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(mixers);

        return mixersConcatenated;
    }
}
```